# Update multiple dynamic nested Firestore fields using FieldPath

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update some Firestore documents in a batch in Nodejs. Some of the fields I'm updating are nested Map fields with periods in their names that are generated dynamically. I understand this has been covered before and the solution is:

```
var email = 'test@email.com';
var myPath = new admin.firestore.FieldPath('email', email);
batch.update(db.collection('collection').doc('document'), myPath, admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete());
```

This would delete the field `"email.'test@email.com'"`. However, I'm trying to update multiple fields like this:

```
var email = 'test@email.com';
var myPath = new admin.firestore.FieldPath('email', email);
var updateObject = {[myPath]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()};
updateObject = {...updateObject, count: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)};
batch.update(db.collection('collection').doc('document'), updateObject);
```

When I try this, the `count` field is updated, but the nested `email` field is unchanged. I'm assuming there is some issue with how I'm getting the `FieldPath` object in there. All the examples I can find only show updating one field at a time. There are also cases where I'll need to update multiple nested fields (such as two fields in the `email` map). How should this be done correctly?

Comment: As far as I can tell this should work. If you log the `updateObject` before calling `update`, does it have the values you'd expect?

Comment: Yes it does: Doc update object: `{'email.\`test@email.com\`': DeleteTransform {},count: NumericIncrementTransform { operand: 1 }}`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this tiny test on a database on my own:

```
const docRef = admin.firestore().doc("68821373/i6ESA7AZwZRhPsdDHGmY");
const updates = {
  toDelete: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
  toIncrement: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
};
docRef.update(updates);
```

This incremented the `toIncrement` field and removed the `toDelete` field. So the operations can be combined in a single call, although I am not sure how your code is different.

---

I also quickly ran a test with a batch, just in case that makes a difference:

```
const docRef = admin.firestore().doc("68821373/i6ESA7AZwZRhPsdDHGmY");
const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
const updates = {
  toDelete: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
  toIncrement: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
};
batch.update(docRef, updates);
await batch.commit();
```

But here too, the increment and delete are both executed without problems for me.

Comment: Could you verify it is working with a nested map field, where the deeper field is a variable with a period in it somewhere? Such as `emailVariable = 'test@test.com'; [email.${emailVariable}]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete()` - that is the main difference I see between our code.

Comment: I just tried that too. It removed the `toDelete` subfield in that case, but leaves the empty parent field. Still not the same problem you're having. Did you already try my simpler code, and did that work for you?

Comment: Yes, I've done updates like you showed above many times. The issue has been the dynamically generated and nested field name that has a period in it. So the reading I've done has pointed to using the `FieldPath` object. But all examples I've found for the `FieldPath` object method have only updated a single field.

Comment: As shown in the code in my answer, this can be done without a fieldpath as far as I know. But I find your object building a bit convoluted. Have you already tried the more basic `const mypath = variable + ".subfield"; updateObject[mypath]: "new Value"`?

Comment: Yes. When I use that method, the console output shows `'email.test@email.com': DeleteTransform {},`, which I believe means it's looking for the nested field email > test@email > com. When I use the `FieldPath` method, the console shows `'email.\`test@email.com\`'`, which should be the path email > test@email.com. But it does not get updated in either instance.

Comment: So I tried with my original method above, but instead of deleting the field I set it to false. Instead of updating the field, it created a new field at `email > \`test@email > com\``. So it clearly seems to be having an issue with the period in the field, and I'm not sure how to get around that.

Comment: Is there a way to try a `set(..., { merge: true })`. Unlike `update` a `set` call does not interpret dots as field separators, so I wonder if the `FieldPath` object will then make it through unharmed.

Comment: I tried with set/merge and got this error: Error writing batch:  {"code":3,"details":"Invalid property path \"`email.\\`test@email.com``\".","metadata":{"internalRepr":{},"options":{}},"note":"Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient"}